# Javascript array, removing the same combination digits but just different order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I just need the logic of removing the same combination 3 digits but just different order and just pushing the lowest value.

Assuming I have the following array:

```
var array = [211, 112, 121, 456, 564, 731, 898];
```

When submitted, it will just push the following array:

```
var array = [112, 456, 731, 898]
```

Since, 211, 112 & 121 are same digits, but just different order and it only pushed 112 since it is the lowest among the three. Same for 456 & 564.

A sample code would be great, can't find it on Stack overflow too.

Comment: One idea is to convert each into a string, split then sort, and finally compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and collect the smallest values for a result array.

This works for an unsorted data.

```js
var array = [211, 112, 121, 456, 564, 731, 898],
    result = Array.from(array.reduce((map, value) => {
        var key = value.toString().split('').sort().join(''),
            last = map.get(key);

        return map.set(key, last < value ? last : value);
    }, new Map).values());
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Kind of what I was about to show, out of curiosity what does using a regex split gain from just doing `.split('')` ?

Comment: @Keith, oh, sorry, it was just funny.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I've done it,..

If your wanting to select the first one, this will keep track using another Set, to see if it has been returned.

edit: to take the smallest, a pre-sort will do this.

```js
const array = [211, 112, 121, 456, 564, 731, 898];

function deDup(arr) {
  const a = arr.sort((a,b) => a -b);
  const got = new Set();
  const mapped = array.map(m => m.toString().split('').sort().join(''));
  const ret = [];
  mapped.forEach((v, ix) => {
    if (got.has(v)) return;
    got.add(v);
    ret.push(a[ix]);
  });
  return ret;
}

console.log(deDup(array));
```

Comment: you take the first value of same, but not the smallest one.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution with `reduce`:

```js
var array = [211, 112, 121, 456, 564, 731, 898];

var result = array.sort().reduce((all, item) => {

    var el = Number(String(item).split('').sort().join(''));

    if (all.indexOf(el) === -1) all.push(item)

    return all;

}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to remove all permutations of a number from the list, try the follwoing:

```js
let array = [211, 112, 121, 456, 564, 731, 898];

array.sort();

var result = [];

let set = new Set();
array.forEach((a)=>{
  let temp = a.toString().split('').sort().join();
  if(set.has(temp))
    return;
  set.add(temp);
  result.push(a);
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

For one-liner and ES6. You can use this

```
Array.from(
 new Set(
  [211, 112, 121, 456, 564, 731, 898]
  .map(x => parseInt(x.toString().split('').sort().join('')))
 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my contribution, very un-optimised and messy and I know there are easier ways above to solve it.

What I have done:

- Iterate over array
- Convert digits `.toString()`
- Get the sum of each string index and create an object with the `sum` and `index`
- The sum will remain the same if the element has the same numbers but in different positions
- Later, removed duplicates for the object
- Return new array

---

```js
let array = [211, 112, 121, 456, 564, 731, 898];

function removeDuplicates(myArr, prop) {
  return myArr.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
    return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
  });
}

function removeSimilar(arr) {
  let arrSums = [];
  let finalArray = [];

  arr.forEach((el, i) => {
    let numStr = el.toString();
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < numStr.length; i++) {
      sum += parseInt(numStr[i]);
    }
    arrSums.push({
      sum: sum,
      index: i
    });
  });

  arrSums = removeDuplicates(arrSums, "sum");

  arrSums.forEach(({index}) => {
    finalArray.push(arr[index]);
  });

  return finalArray;
}

console.log(removeSimilar(array));
```